# Interrupt thread of other process

Tags: java, multithreading, java-6

It may happen a thread is waiting on an object monitor and never wakes up because no other thread is notifying it (which of course is a bug...).
Using the `jstack` utility I see all threads and their name and status.

Is it possible to interrupt a thread (so it throws an `InterruptedException`) from the command line or anyway from within a different process?

I know about the https://github.com/jglick/jkillthread utility but that one simply kills the thread and I need the thread to be **interrupted**.

The reason for the question is that I got this situation in a production environment that I cannot simply restart....

Comment: Nope no way to do that - unless you write something like that on your own

Comment: @Antoniossss: is it possible to write some external program (for instance, that uses the Attach Listener) that does the stuff without having to stop the processes currently running or do you mean to write something within the program that's having problems (in which case of course I'll have to restart everything)? I already found a solution for the 2nd option but I don't wanna restart it.

Comment: Both would work. Either add feature to your app, or write something like java agent.

Comment: @Antoniossss any idea how to write something external? I never used the attach listener or hotspot. Can you provide a link to some examples?

Comment: Just  thinking everything you need is provided in the jkillthread utility. Changing line 51 of Agent.java to thread.interrupt should do the trick...

Comment: @leftbit that's my boy!!