# Can I force an interruption inside a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a class that sends some content thrugh the net. I had some issuse because a file sending didn't ended after more than 10 hours, I think for connection interruptions.

I though to put the sender method into a different thread and try to interrupt it after a timeout if it wasn't ended yet. But the issue is inside a kernel class, and I cannot put into it a query to check if Therad.isinterrupted is checked.

Can I truncate a thread without ask him to terminate via the interrupt method?

Thank you,
Lucio Menci

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331270/interrupt-thread-of-other-process

Comment: Since you're not showing code, and not telling us anything about the method that gets stuck, it will be hard to give you any quality advice. If the entire process of sending is handled in a library you don't control, and you can't create a version that sends, for example, 1K at a time, it's going to be hard. Try to use a different library.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.interrupt()` interrupts the thread immediately

`Thread.stop()` is Deprecated and throws a unsupportedoperationexception

From java doc:

Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it is to stop running. If the target thread waits for long periods (on a condition variable, for example), the interrupt method should be used to interrupt the wait.

Answer (score 0):

Good strategy in that case will be to close socket connection itself, that will cause any pending `write` actions to abort and throw `SocketException`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()

```
class FileTransfer
{
    protected Socket theSocket;

    //...
    public void sendFile() throws Exception
    {
         // ...
         theSocket = new Socket(...);
         // ...
    }

    public void abortTransfer() throws Exception
    {
        // This may be called from another thread so do not mark it as synchronized
        theSocket.close(); // At this point sendFile() with throw exception SocketException
    }
    // ...
}
```

For sure, you may need to add some extra tricky logic to deal with race conditions to do it in most generic way (I omitted it for clarity). Anyway, the whole idea is simple: close socket from another thread and you will have pending `write` operations terminated.